# Filtrar valores de un HashMap con Stream

Tags: java, stream

Tengo un HashMap cuya clave es un String y su valor un ArrayList que almacena objetos de tipo Clase. Necesito saber si existe algún valor cuyo atributo sea "blablabla". Estoy tratando de realizar la búsqueda utilizando la clase Stream. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class Clase
{ private String codigo = ""; ... }
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Clase>> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Clase>> ();
if (myHashMap.values()
.stream()
.filter(e -> e.codigo.equals ("blablabla"))
.findFirst() != null)
throw new RuntimeExcepcion...
```

El código, evidentemente no funciona porque la estructura de los datos es una Collection<ArrayList>; el problema es que no sé cómo poder acceder a cada uno de los ArrayList.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando flatMap es una opción

```
if( myHashMap.values().stream()
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
    .anyMatch(p -> p.getCodigo().equals("blablabla")))
{ // lo que quieras hacer }
```

**flatMap** : toma una entrada, en tu caso una lista, y genera como salida un stream con los elementos de la lista.

**l -> l.stream()** : se encarga de generar el stream de cada lista.

**anyMatch** busca si algún elemento cumple con el predicado ( condición ).

**p -> p.getCodigo().equals("blablabla")** : p es un elemento de tipo Clave y pregunta si el *codigo" de ese elemento es igual a "blablabla".

Asumo que los objetos Clase tienen un getter para el campo *codigo* ya que en tu ejemplo es private dicho campo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que la colección a la que intentas acceder, también requiere un stream para poder operar sobre ella.

Además, si lo que queremos es saber si alguno de los valores de una lista cumple una condición, la función lamba **anyMatch** nos devuelve directamente un booleano.

De esta manera, podemos recorrer en una sola sentencia, la coleción de cada uno de los registros del mapa

```
if (myHashMap.values()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(x -> x.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.codigo.equals ("blablabla"))))
```

Primero **values()** nos devuelve los valores del mapa

Con **stream()** hacemos que esa lista de valores sea operable

La función **anyMatch()** comprueba que alguno de los valores cumpla una condición

Esa condición a su vez realiza **stream()** para operar en la colección, de nuevo **anyMatch()** para comprobar que alguno de sus miembros cumplen la condición sobre el atributo final

Comment: Tu respuesta quedaría mucho mejor si explicas como funciona y como resuelve el problema de OP. ;)